# Inserting an item in a sharepoint list that has a lookup column

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to insert an item in a sharepoint list that has two lookup columns. After executing the code shown below, I've successfully inserted the item into the list, but the lookup columns do not contain any value. I've made certain that the id of the lookup item is very well existing in my second list,and if I put a random id, I got an exception that tells me that the item can't be inserted at all. So, the problem isn't related to an id problem. 
this is a screen shot of my list: [image: https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img921/3483/J08viH.png]

My Code:

```
function ajout_table_double() {
    var nom_local=document.getElementById('localField').value;
    if (idSanByOrder.length>=1) {
        for(var i = 0;i < idSanByOrder.length;i++){
            clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
            var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Plat_FastFood');
            var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
            this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

            var lookupSingle = new SP.FieldLookupValue();  
            var lookupSingle2 = new SP.FieldLookupValue();  
            lookupSingle.set_lookupId(idSanByOrder[i]); // i've tried putting directly the id's value directly, but same problem occured
            lookupSingle2.set_lookupId(local_tab[0]);

            oListItem.set_item('fast_food_column', lookupSingle);  
            oListItem.set_item('plat_column', lookupSingle2);  
            oListItem.set_item('Title', 'local: '+nom_local);

            oListItem.update();

            clientContext.load(oListItem);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryDoubleSucc), 
                Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryDoubleFail)
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script seems fine, try to confirm the ID is correct.

My tested script.

```
function InsertItem() {
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();            
            var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("MyList2");
            var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
            var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
            var lookupSingle = new SP.FieldLookupValue();            
            lookupSingle.set_lookupId(9);            
            oListItem.set_item('Title', 'testInsert');
            oListItem.set_item('plat_column', lookupSingle);
            oListItem.update();
            clientContext.load(oListItem);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                Function.createDelegate(this,
                    function () {
                        ItemIDCache = oListItem.get_id();
                        alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
                    }),
                Function.createDelegate(this,
                    function (sender, args) {
                        console.log(args);
                    }));

        }
```

Comment: I'm 100% positive that the ID is correct. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah, i've just realised that i've reverted the two IDs. Thanks brother!